# Роли в asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

У меня есть сайт на шарпе, там настроены две роли админ и юзер, если я логинюсь как админ, я вижу один функционал, если как юзер - другой, для меня это уже ого-го-го,

```
<div class="text-center">
    @if (User.IsInRole(qwh.Utility.Helper.Admin))
    {
        <h1 class="display-4">You logged as an admin!</h1>

        <a class="text-dark nav-link" style="margin-left: -150px" asp-action="List" asp-controller="Home">List</a>
    }
    @if (User.IsInRole(qwh.Utility.Helper.User))
    {
        <h1 class="display-4">You logged as an user!</h1>
        <h1 class="display-4">so you have not any rights, looser!</h1>

    }
    else
    {
        <h1 class="display-4">to get access you need to log in!</h1>
    }
</div>
```

Но Я бы хотел, чтобы если я захожу как User александр петров, мне выдаётся одно содержимое, если как данила козловский, то другое содержимое, ну как на реальных сайтах, у каждого свой аккаунт, предположим это дневник электронный, я зарегался там понаписывал, как у меня прошел день и этот позор будет доступен только мне, а не каким-то там петькам или сашкам, как это делается, вряд ли в деталях можно это описать, подскажите что почитать по конкретнее

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/15.1.php Прочитай всю главу "Аутентификация и авторизация". По необходимости следующую за ней - "Identity"

Comment: Читайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0). В меню слева выбирайте пункты, с которыми хотите ознакомиться. В левом нижнем углу можно сменить язык.

Comment: та я и на иязычном шпрехаю чуть-чуть, а на пальцах, ребят, нужно скорее клеймы использовать или роли или может я вообще не туда смотрю, ибо я прочитал на метаните главу по аутентификации - ответа не нашёл, по identity я читал раньше, может пропустил что, не спорю, это возможно, но там речь в основном о том, что ограничить доступ тем кто 1) младше 18 или из компании microsoft или из лондона... но мне нужно чтобы было сё индивидуально, я зашёл, там только мой контент, ладно, я ещё посмотрю, но там вдруг кто понял меня, но если нет, не страшно, всем спасибо)

Comment: В документации смотрите разделы по Identity. Там несложно, но в один короткий ответ не берусь уместить.